# Handling multiple windows in PyGTK/GtkBuilder

Tags: python, pygtk, glade, gtkbuilder

How can I store multiple different windows/dialogs in a single GtkBuilder file and then load these windows in different classes (each class corresponding to a different window)? For instance, currently I'm doing things like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file('gtkbuilder.xml')
    self.welcome_dialog = self.builder.get_object('welcome_dialog')
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.welcome_dialog.show()
```

This does produce a functioniong piece of software, but it spits out all kinds of warnings like:

```
welcome_dialog.py:38: RuntimeWarning: missing handler 'on_contract_window_response'
  self.builder.connect_signals(self)
```

for each of the signal handlers I have defined in Glade for all the other windows. I guess all I want to do is connect the signals for this single window/dialog and ignore everything else, but I'm not sure how to do that. Or maybe I am doing something horribly wrong and I should be splitting up each window into a different GtkBuilder file? Or connecting the signals for every possible window at the same (initial) time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `gtk.Builder.add_from_file` adds the entire hierarchy from your file to the Builder object, which is why you're getting the signal connection warnings; the `builder.connect_signals()` call tries to connect up *everything*.

Instead, use [`gtk.Builder.add_objects_from_file`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkbuilder.html#method-gtkbuilder--add-objects-from-file) to choose the individual top-level window or widget that you want to handle in your current class.